# What does "one's" mean in this definition?

Tags: possessives

Google Dict defines "Reside": Have one's permanent home in a particular place. Does "one's" mean other person's home which doesn't belong to the speaker?

Answer (score 1):

***[One’s](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ones)***:

> Speakers and writers use one's to indicate that something belongs or relates to people in general, or to themselves in particular.
>
> - ...a feeling of responsibility for the welfare of others in one's community.
> - It seems to me a fatal illusion to expect one's children simply to reproduce one's own views.

(Collins Dictionary;

- In your sentence “one’s” refers to people in general.